# How I can add condition with context attribute in Orocommerce API processor?

Tags: api, orocommerce

In Oro docs I found that I can add condition to run api processor only when certain attribute in context object exists/not exists:

[image]

But I can't understand what is context attribute. Is it not the same as underlying entity attribute?
I tried to add this to processor condition, but it seems always not exist even if it is in the context entity:

```
client_bundle.api.fill_order_line_item_price:
  parent: oro_order.api.fill_order_line_item_price
  tags:
    - { name: oro.api.processor, action: customize_form_data, event: post_validate, requestType: '!frontend', class: Oro\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\OrderLineItem, fromExternalSource: exists, priority: -20 }
```

How can I use this condition to run processor only for some entities and not interfering into processor logic?

Answer (score 0):

**Context** is an object that is used to store the input and output data and share data between processors.

Here is the documentation about the Context class methods: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/actions/#context-class.

There are many useful entity-related attributes in it.